# What does "Time" in the Geth VM Trace Transaction refer to?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, rinkeby

I'm new to Ethereum world, and I need some declaration,

I used "Rinkeby network" and just found Geth VM Trace Transaction

```
{
 "type": "CALL",
  "from": "0x6f1e5fc933898859686a4d39f4430316be589f5e",
  "to": "0xb61e9cb66cb5b2ca9d6f4db003c364d0698cac33",
  "value": "0x0",
  "gas": "0x5b3770",
  "gasUsed": "0x2b03",
  "input": "0xfc62b26d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000001c67eacc46c5c3727b4300597acc07fe4a9ad6c5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001146313a32303a45353a41433a36473a4131000000000000000000000000000000",
  "output": "0x",
  "time": "5.0133ms"
}
```

My question:

**What the time": "5.0133ms is referring to?**

Is it transaction execution time, or time spent to add the transaction to the block

Appreciate your help

Comment: What's not readable about `5.0133ms`?

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was a little bit confusing. I want to know what the time": "5.0133ms is referring to? Is it the transaction execution time, or time spent to add the transaction to the block, or something else.